# objects convert using js toString() method gives Odd result?

Tags: javascript, oop

code in the below shown results of few conversions of data types using `toString()` method.
all other data types can convert to strings using `toString()` method but when try to convert object to string using `toString()` method it gives  odd result it is "[object Object]"

```
var b =1
b.toString();// produce "1"


var x=function(){var y=1;};
x.toString();// produce "function (){var y=1;}"


var z = [1,2];
z.toString();// produce "1,2"

var a = new Date;
//a = Date {Thu Dec 25 2014 22:44:32 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)}
a.toString();// produce "Thu Dec 25 2014 22:44:32 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)"



var obj = { name: 'John' }
obj.toString();// produce "[object Object]"
```

i wanna know when we try to convert object to string using `toString()` method why it gives a odd result .

instead of giving  "[object Object]" why wont `toString()` method returns this value "{ name: 'John' }"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript all objects inherit from Object. For a custom object if you don't define the toString() method it will inherit it from its parent class. So obj.toString() prints "[object Object]" because it is an object (a primitive type) of type Object.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has several built-in Objects,

Eg:

- JavaScript Number Object
- JavaScript Boolean Object
- JavaScript String Object
- JavaScript Array Object
- JavaScript Date Object
- JavaScript Math Object
- JavaScript RegExp Object

Each Object has the `toString` method implemented in different ways.

---

For user-defined objects the default toString method returns `[object Object]`. You can override it if you want..

```js
function Car(type){
    this.type = type;
}

Car.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.type + " car";
}

var car = new Car('bmw');
alert(car.toString());// produce "bmw car"
```

Also you can even rewrite `Object.prototype.toString` method (but may be not a good idea).

```js
Object.prototype.toString = function() {
   return JSON.stringify(this);    ;
}

var obj = { name: 'John' }
alert(obj.toString());// produce "{ "name": "John"}"
```

Comment: insted of giving  "[object Object]" why wont toString() method returns this value "{ name: 'John' }"

Comment: Because the method `Object.prototype.toString` is implemented to return `[object Object]`. It's not implemented to return "{name: 'John'}"

Comment: why... Object.prototype.toString is implemented to return [object Object] ...? insted of object convert to string like this "{ name: 'John' }"

Comment: I think I just understood what your question is.. :) I have seen some usage of `Object.prototype.toString` to get the type of Objects. May be it's because of that... There is another function `JSON.stringify` to get the results what you expected with `toString` method. However I'm not exactly sure why `[object Object]`....

Comment: i think something regarding about this in this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151809/why-does-object-prototype-tostring-always-return-object
but i don't understand it...